# Asp.Net core MVC Microsoft Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am having one problem with my MVC asp.net core site. I am tring to get data from db, then paste them inside combobox. I really dont know what is causing this error message to appear:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqhWk.png) 
My Startup

```
services.AddDbContext<ConnectionStringClass>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("GETDATA"))); //Stored in json
```

My Index.cshtml in /Views/Home

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<select id="Select1" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.displaydata,"Id","CisloReklamace"))">
            <options value="" selected disabled>

            </options>
        </select>
```

My HomeController in /Views/Home

```
private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly ConnectionStringClass _db;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, ConnectionStringClass db)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _db = db;
        }

        public IEnumerable<EmpClass> displaydata { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            displaydata = await _db.Reklamace.ToListAsync();
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = new HomeController(_logger, _db);
            return View(model);
        }

        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
```

My EmpClass in .Models

```
public class EmpClass
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CisloReklamace { get; set; }
        public string IdAdresa { get; set; }
        public string Zakazka { get; set; }
    }
```

My ConnectionStringClass in .Models

```
public class ConnectionStringClass: DbContext
    {
        public ConnectionStringClass(DbContextOptions<ConnectionStringClass> options): base(options)
        {

        }

        public DbSet<EmpClass> Reklamace { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: As shown in your error message, your selectlist is null i.e. no items to iterate. You aren't passing EmpClass as a model, instead your homecontroller; not sure why. This looks very confusing.

Comment: Ok, how can I pass My class as model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = await _db.Reklamace.ToListAsync();
        return View(model);
    }
```

view

```
@model IEnumerable<EmpClass>

<select id="Select1" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.displaydata,"Id","CisloReklamace"))">
            <options value="" selected disabled>

            </options>
        </select>
```

In controller you pass model which getting on view `@model IEnumerable<EmpClass>`. In your code you trying pass model as HomeController. So your view can't bind model and you got error = null exception